# Aligning text in the center after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I am rotating the view and resizing and moving around UITextFields when this occurs. The only problem is that the placeholder text no longer stays in the middle. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with UIKit. This code was executed on rotation for both portrait and landscape:

```
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

The text field's textAlignment property is moved to the left, then back to the center, almost refreshing it. If I try running the code without moving it to the left first, it doesn't work.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in iOS 5.